# Nokia wrt widget not working with Nokia E63, E71

Tags: widget, nokia-wrt

I have made a **nokia wrt widget, which connects to the server at startup**.

The app **works on most of the devices, but not on E63 and E71.**

**At start-up i call sendRequest() method which has http connection like below:**

loginReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
    try {
        netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
    } 
    catch (e) {
```

alert('exception: ' + e); // i get exception here...
        }

loginReq.onreadystatechange = function(){

```
        if (loginReq.readyState == 4) {

            if (loginReq.status == 200) {

                loginResponseString = loginReq.responseText;
            }
 }
```

}

**The exception is: ReferenceError - Can't find variable: netscape.**

Please help.

Regards,
Namit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually in the below line...
xmlHttp.open('POST', url_frame, true);.....................(1)

The devices on which the client server Nokia WRT widget app didnt work were:
Nokia E63, Nokia E51, Nokia E71.

The above devices belongs to **Symbian S60 3rd Edition Feature Pack1**

On these devices **'POST'** mentioned in (1) does not work unfortunately.

So we need to use xmlHttp.open('GET', url_frame, true);.....................(2) i.e GET in nokia wrt widget for client server application.

**Conclusion:** To the best of my knowledge, **Symbian S60 3rd Edition Feature pack2** devices does not support for **POST** in **Nokia WRT Widget.**

I have tested the above on these 3 devices.  If someone has any other specific reasons about it or has opinions different than mine, please post it...

Regards,
Namit.